# 1 to the power of infinity formula

Tags: calculus, limits

There is a general formula for indeterminate form $1 ^ {\infty}$ which I'm looking for a proof which is also used [here](http://www.vitutor.com/calculus/limits/one_infinity.html). ([picture](https://web.archive.org/web/20131018204213/http://www.vitutor.com/calculus/limits/images/lim_15.gif))

> Given $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$$, what is
> $$\lim_{x\to a} f^{g} = e^{\lim_{x\to a}{(f-1)g}}\quad ? $$

I would appreciate it if somone could give me a proof of this formula.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I 'm looking for a proof @zahbaz

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe this is where the identity is coming from.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a}f^g &= \lim_{x\to a}(1+f-1)^g
\\
&= \lim_{x\to a}\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{f-1}\right)}\right)^g
\\
\\
&= \lim_{x\to a}\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{f-1}\right)}\right)^{g\frac{f-1}{f-1}}
\\
\\
&= \lim_{x\to a}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{f-1}\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{f-1}}\right]^{g(f-1)}
\\
\\
&= \lim_{x\to a}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{f-1}\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{f-1}}\right]^{\lim_{x\to a}g(f-1)} \qquad (*)
\\
\\
&= e^{\lim_{x\to a}g(f-1)}
\end{align}

Where the first limit is a form of the limit definition of $e$. I put a note (*) next to one step I am uneasy about. I am unsure why we can separately evaluate limits here. Perhaps someone else can comment on this.

Comment: This works when the limits both exist, since $\exp$ and $\log$ are both continuous. (Phrase $\lim r^s$ as $\lim \exp(s \log r)$, and use that the limit of a product is the product of the limits.)

Answer (score 18):

Remember that $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$, so to be more precise, we should write $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ instead of $f$ and $g$. This applies to the answer below and to the other answers which have also adopted the shorthand used in the question of $f$ for $f(x)$ and $g$ for $g(x)$.

---

If $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f=1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\lim_{x\to a}f^g\right)
&=\lim_{x\to a}\log\left(f^g\right)\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{x\to a}\log(f)\,g\\
&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\log(f)}{f-1}\lim_{x\to a}\,(f-1)\,g\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{x\to a}\,(f-1)\,g
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f^g=\exp\left(\lim\limits_{x\to a}\,(f-1)\,g\right)
$$

Comment: How did you get $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \log(f)/(f-1) = 1$ in the 4th step?  I used l'Hopital's to verify it, but often this formula is taught to students before they see derivatives, so I'm wondering if it can be proved without resort to calculus?!

Comment: Without calculus, we are limited in the ways to define $\log(x)$. One way is to define $e^x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$. Then [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says not only that $e^x\ge1+x$, but also that $e^{-x}\ge1-x$ which implies that $e^x\le\frac1{1-x}$. Substituting $x\mapsto\log(x)$ and rearranging gives, for $x\gt0$, $$\frac{x-1}x\le\log(x)\le x-1$$ which says that $$\min\left(\tfrac1x,1\right)\le\frac{\log(x)}{x-1}\le\max\left(\tfrac1x,1\right)$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? I appreciate your opinion, but it is hard to fix something without knowing what is broken.

Answer (score 9):

$$\begin{align}
\lim \limits_{x \to a} f^g = e^{\lim \limits_{x \to a} g\cdot \log[1+ (f-1)]}
&= e^{\lim_{x \to a} g\cdot [(\frac{(f-1)}{1}) + (\frac{(f-1)^2}{2}) + (\frac{(f-1)^3}{3}) + ...]} \\
&= e^{\lim \limits_{x \to a} g\cdot (f-1)[1 + (\frac{(f-1)}{1}) + (\frac{(f-1)^2}{2}) + ...]}.
\end{align}$$

Now, since $f \to 1$ when $x \to a$, all the subsequent terms in the expansion involving $(f-1)$ will become zero, and the expression becomes:

$$\lim_{x \to a} f^g = e^{\lim \limits_{x \to a} g\cdot (f-1)}.$$

Comment: I don't know how to write all that math here, though I tried hard to copy and paste these expressions with necessary edits from the tutorial page. This is my first answer, any help regarding editing will be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Fischer.

Answer (score -1):

It's wrong in the general.

It's true if there exist $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}g(f-1)$ and

there is $\delta>0$ for which $f\neq1$ for any $0<|x-a|<\delta$ we have $f(x)\neq1$.

Indeed, since $h(x)=e^x$ is a continues function we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f^g=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}e^{\frac{\ln(1+f-1)}{f-1}\cdot g(f-1)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}\left(\frac{\ln(1+f-1)}{f-1}\cdot g(f-1)\right)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}g(f-1)}.$$

Comment: I belive there is no need in the assumtion that $f \neq 1$ in a neirbourhood of $a$. See Daniel Fischer's proof.

Comment: @Enzo Giannotta  Maybe. It not says that my reasoning is wrong. By the way, why does in the solution there exist $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}g(f-1)$? It's not given!