# Find the limit $\lim_{x \to 1}(\frac{3x}{2+x})^\frac{x}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, natural-numbers

Find the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}\left(\frac{3x}{2+x}\right)^\frac{x}{1-x}
$$

I've transformed the function by changing limit of 1 to zero and become the following:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1 + \frac{3x-3}{x-3}\right)^\frac{1 - x}{x}
$$

I spent many time and tried to transform the power part $\frac{1 - x}{x}$ to $\frac{x-3}{3x-3}$ but still can't remove the $x$'s on final. How can I find this limit? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It must be something wrong here with your change: setting $x=0$ in the second expression results in $1+1=2$ in the parenthesis, however it was $1$ earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
L=\lim_{x \to a}(f(x))^{g(x)}  
$$
So, if $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x))=1,\lim_{x \to a}(g(x))= \infty $
$$
\ln L=\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)-1)({g(x)})  
$$
In your case,
$$
L=\lim_{x \to 1}(\frac{3x}{2+x})^{\frac{x}{1-x}}  
$$
Therefore,
$$
\ln L=\lim_{x \to 1}(\frac{3x}{2+x}-1)({\frac{x}{1-x}})  
$$
$$
\ln L=\lim_{x \to 1}(\frac{2x-2}{2+x})({\frac{x}{1-x}})  
$$
$$
\ln L=\lim_{x \to 1}(\frac{-2x}{2+x}) 
$$
$$
L= e^{\frac{-2}{3}}  
$$

Proof of the first claim is here: [1 to the power of infinity formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987215/1-to-the-power-of-infinity-formula)

Comment: This should be community wiki I guess

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi What exactly is  'community wiki'?

Comment: Thank you very much, The deduction of this general formula is something new to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to match
$$
\frac{3x}{2+x}=1+\frac1t\iff t=\frac{x+2}{2(x-1)}.
$$
Now
$$
\frac{x}{1-x}=t\cdot\frac{-2x}{x+2}.
$$
What is the limit of
$$
\left[\left(1+\frac1t\right)^t\right]^{-\frac{2x}{x+2}}?
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\Bigg[\frac{3x}{2+x}\Bigg]^\frac{x}{1-x}$$ Make $x=1+y$ to work around $y=0$. So
$$A=\Bigg[\frac{3y+3}{y+3}\Bigg]^{-\frac{y+1}{y}}=\Bigg[3-\frac{6}{y+3}\Bigg]^{-\frac{y+1}{y}}$$
$$\log(A)=-\frac{y+1}{y}\log\Bigg[3-\frac{6}{y+3}\Bigg]$$ Now, by Taylor
$$\log\Bigg[3-\frac{6}{y+3}\Bigg]=\frac{2 y}{3}-\frac{4 y^2}{9}+O\left(y^3\right)$$
$$\log(A)=-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2 y}{9}+O\left(y^2\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{e^{2/3}}-\frac{2 y}{9 e^{2/3}}+O\left(y^2\right)$$