# Why is $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1x$ is $e$ and not $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am a grade 12th student. I am having doubts about limits as follows:-

If $a>1$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}a^x = \infty$.

The above is because a number greater than $1$ when multiplied with itself, increases. If we do it a large number of times, the number will get close to $\infty$. Therefore its limiting value becomes $\infty$.

Applying same logic $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1x = \infty$.

But $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1x = e$.

Can anyone suggest to me where I am wrong?

## **Edit**

I had asked my mentor about this. He said the following.

In case of $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}a^x$, base and exponent are independent of each other whereas in case of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1x$, the base and exponent are dependent on each other. Because of this dependence, as soon as we create the base, i.e. $(1+x)$, $x$ becomes fixed and as a result the exponent becomes fixed and can't approach infinity. However, for $a^x$, $x$ can become as small as we want and therefore tends to infinity.

Can anyone please explain me why are we trying to fix the base in case of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1x$? Is there any such rule that we have to first create a base and then apply the limits? Am I having a wrong interpretation of limits? Can anyone please interpret his statements in a simplified language.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: While $\dfrac1x$ increases, $1+x$ decreases. The two effects compensate each other.

Comment: Take the logarithm of your expression...

Comment: Note that, exponent and denominator depends on each other. e.g. $1=\lim_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1{x^2}≠\lim_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1{x}=e$. This called just $1^{\infty}=0×\infty=\text{indeterminate}$. Because, $0×\infty$ can equal to "anything".

Comment: I am extremely sorry to all for my carelessness. It should be a>1 instead of a >0

Comment: One day you may study calculus.  Your calculus text will have a discussion of 'indeterminate forms'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topic here is "indeterminate forms."  In most interesting limits, there is one quantity trying to make the function small and another trying to make it large.  They battle it out and when the smoke clears, you get to see who won and by how much.  For instance,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}  \frac{x+1}{x-1}.$$

The $x+1$ is trying to make the function large (infinity).  The $x-1$ (since it's on the bottom) is trying to make the function small (zero).  When the war is over, they compromise and the limit is $1$.

What you're doing is the equivalent of changing one of the $x$'s into a constant, but letting the other $x$ go to infinity.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}  \frac{a+1}{x-1} = 0,$$

so the limit comes out different because the top is no longer varying.

In your limit, the $1+x$ is racing toward $\infty,$  so this bit is trying to make the limit $\infty$.   The exponent $1/x$ is raising a number to a power close to zero, so it's trying to make the limit $1$.

As the exponent runs to zero, making the limit smaller, the base is running towards $\infty$, making the limit larger.  The compromise in the end is that the limit is $e$.

The quantity $a$ is not $\infty$ and isn't trying to get there.  He loses the battle because he's not even trying.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that the first statement should really be

> If $a$ is a constant greater than $1$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}a^x=\infty$.

It is normally understood that if you say "Let $a>1$", or similar, that you are talking about a specific, constant real number $a$.

Here, it's important that $a$ does not depend on $x$, and without that restriction the statement wouldn't be true. It's easier to see this by replacing $a$ with $\sqrt[x]2$; then certainly $\sqrt[x]2>1$ for any $x$, but $(\sqrt[x]2)^x=2$ for every $x$, so its limit is also $2$.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for my carelessness. It should be a>1 instead of a >0

Comment: @user12137152 no worries, sorry for not spotting that myself!

Comment: The first two lines of this answer are incorrect. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: All I see is a typo (the limit being $0$ instead of $\infty$), which I've just fixed by editing the answer. Did I miss something else?

Comment: No you didn't miss anything else, I believe. That mistake is what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\left(1+\frac12\right)^2=1+\frac22+\frac14<\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}\\
\left(1+\frac13\right)^3=1+\frac33+\frac39+\frac1{27}<\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}\\
\left(1+\frac14\right)^4=1+\frac44+\frac6{16}+\frac4{64}+\frac1{256}<\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}\\
\left(1+\frac15\right)^5=1+\frac55+\frac{10}{25}+\frac{10}{125}+\frac5{625}+\frac1{3125}<\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\frac1{5!}\\
$$

as you can check term-wise, and this generalizes to any power. The series on the right is quickly convergent to $2.718281828\cdots$

Comment: I am extremely sorry for my carelessness. It should be a>1 instead of a >0

Comment: Thank you for answering. From your proof, it is clear that the expression evaluates to e but what I wish to know is why the logic which I have used is wrong.

Comment: @user12137152: I said it in a comment and this proof is an additional explanation.

Comment: @user12137152: also note that this proof does not show at all that the expression converges to $e$. It merely shows an upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}a^x=+\infty\,\,\, a \in (1,+\infty)$$
And:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$$
In the first case $a$ is **fixed** and $a\in(1,+\infty)$. In the second case, we have what we call an exponential indertinate form. This is of the type:
$$[1^{\infty}]$$
Where that $1$ indicates that you are considering a quantity that is **very close to $1$, but it's never $1$**. We can write $1+\epsilon$.

I hope you know that:
$$e=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$
In particular, in sequence world, we have the following **Theorem**: let $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, we have that:
$$2\geq a_n \leq 3$$
We **define** to be the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=e$$
This theorem can be generalized to the real world.

We let $t=\frac{1}{x}$. When $x\to 0^+$, $t\to +\infty$. So, we have:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{t\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t=e$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. But the answer still doesn't identify the mistake in my logic. No doubt that the expression evaluates to $e$ as it is the definition of $e$. What I want is why is my logic is wrong and not how it evaluates to $e$.

Comment: I am sorry @user12137152 . But this post(+1) does explain why your logic is wrong .You have to appreciate the fact that you are dealing with indeterminate forms and there cannot be any one "absolute explanation" as to why your logic is wrong. Obviously there was some "logic" into naming it as "indeterminate". This answer has clearly explained that you are fixing $a>1$ and in the question $(1+x)$ is getting infinitesemally close to $1$. There is a strict difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to understand why the limit does not diverge (equal infinity) is to consider the sequence $$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$
Taking the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is the same as asking what $\lim_{x\to 0_+}{(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}}$ is.

This sequence is bounded and increasing. To show it is increasing you need the binomial theorem and because it is bounded (show this with $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\leq \sum_{k=0}^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$),  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\lim_{x\to 0_+}{(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}}<\infty$.

Your logic fails, because while it is true that for $a>1:lim_{x\to\infty}a^x=\infty$, you have to consider $\lim_{x\to 0_+} (1+x)\ngtr 1$, which is why the rule is not applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

This can be rearranged a little bit.

$$\lim_{x -> 0^+} (1+x)^{1/x}=\lim_{N-> \infty } (1+\frac{1}{N})^N$$

by The Binomial Theorem:

$$(1+\frac{1}{N})^N=\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{N!}{k!(N-k)!}\frac{1}{N^k}=\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{\frac{N}{N}\frac{N-1}{N}\frac{N-2}{N}...\frac{N-k+1}{N}}{k!}<\frac{5}{2}+\sum_{k=3}^N\frac{1}{k!}<\frac{5}{2}+\sum_{k=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{11}{4}<\infty$$

for all N>2.

The series is bounded by the Comparison Test with geometric series in which the common term is $1/2$. It also increases monotonically with N, so by the Increasing Monotone Sequence theorem, it converges.

The combination of the high exponent and the infinitesimal increase of 1 actually cancels out to an infinite sum of the products of many terms most of which are less than 1 which are further divided by the fast-growing factorial function. The base isn't constant, so weird things can happen.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But it still doesn't clarifies the mistake in my logic. No doubt it proves that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1x$ can't be $\infty$ but the answer doesn't identify the mistake in my logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987215/1-to-the-power-of-infinity-formula)

Using this you easily get that the limit is $e$.

You also might want to consider the proof of $2<\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}<3$ . [Here's](https://planetmath.org/convergenceofthesequence11nn#:%7E:text=%2C%20we%20can%20say%20that%20the,sup%20n%20%E2%88%88%20%E2%84%95%20%E2%81%A1) a proof

Comment: Thank you for answering. But there is a problem. The answer does explains why $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}(1+ x)^\frac1x$ is $e$. But what I want to know is the fault in my logic as described in the question and not how it evaluates to $e$.

Comment: As many comments have said. This form is $1^{\infty}$ form. It is indeterminate. That is why the best way to understand this to consider the real sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ and see that it's limit is $e$. What you are essentially doing is considering substituting $x=\frac{1}{n}$. So as $x\to 0^+$ , $n\to\infty$ . These things will become more clear to you when you study real analysis. But as of now it is sufficient to know that $1^{\infty}$ is indeterminate .

Comment: @user12137152 . And a complete rigourous proof will be taught to you when you take Real analysis. You have to approach through sequences in order to prove this. Then you will be dealing with natural numbers which will be easier to work with than these reals. After that when you learn continuity and the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a "complete" metric space , only then it will be absolutely clear as to why your initial thinking is wrong. We all did calculus in high school and these things caused confusions to us too.

Comment: @user12137152 . It is my advice to you as a Masters student in Mathematics that you take this an indeterminate form and stick to formulas for evaluating them at this stage. Right now you do not even have knowledge of accumulation points of sets in order for any of us to explain it to you in terms of analysis. To be more specific you are not looking at the limit of a single function , but the limit of a composition of continuous functions. So you have to be careful while evaluating the limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=(1+ x)^\frac1x\implies \log(y)=\frac1x \log(1+x)$$ When $x$ is small, $$\log(1+x)\sim x\implies \log(y)\sim 1 \implies y=e^{\log(y)}\sim e$$