# Evaluate: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)^x
$$
where $a>0$ and $c>0$.

What I tried:
$$
\left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)^x = \left(\frac{a+(b/x)}{c+(d/x)}\right)^x = \frac{(a+(b/x))^x}{(c+(d/x))^x} 
$$
Because I wanted to use the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right
)^t=e
$$
But now I stuck. How to solve it?

Comment: This is the right thing to do when $a=c$. Otherwise, getting the limit is easier. Go back to the definition $r^x = \exp(x \ln r)$ when $r>0$.

Comment: Or another way is think about $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=1+\frac{bc-ad}{acx+ad}$

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Can you please explain a bit more how it can help here? Still don't see it

Comment: If any of the 2 answers is satisfactory, please mark it as accepted. If not, make sure to tell us what it is you feel like needs clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right idea. Let me redirect you to the correct way to think.

So, yes you need to use $e$ at some point, but before that you need to get rid of that annoying $x$ in the exponent. An easy way to do that is to apply $\ln$ to your limit, let me show you:
$$\ln(\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln((\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^x) $$
Now, we use the fact:
$$\ln(a^x) = x\ln(a)$$
So, we get:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln((\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} x\ln(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})$$
All we need to solve is $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x(a+\frac bx)}{x(c+\frac dx)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a+\frac bx}{c+\frac dx}  = \frac ac$.

Case 1: $\frac ac \gt 1 \Rightarrow \ln(\frac ac) \gt 0$

Now we can find the limit: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\ln(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}) = \infty \cdot \ln(\frac ac) = + \infty$$

Finally, we shouldn't forget that we applied $\ln$ at the start so we must **undo** it! To do that, we must apply $e$ to the result since $e^{\ln x} = x$.

So, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^x = e^{\infty} = \infty $$

---

Case 2: $0 \lt \frac ac \lt 1 \Rightarrow \ln(\frac ac) \lt 0$

Now we can find the limit: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\ln(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}) = \infty \cdot \ln(\frac ac) = - \infty$$

Finally, we shouldn't forget that we applied $\ln$ at the start so we must **undo** it! To do that, we must apply $e$ to the result since $e^{\ln x} = x$.

So, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^x = e^{- \infty} = 0 $$

---

Case 3: $\frac ac = 1 \Rightarrow \ln(\frac ac) = 0$

If we were to find the limit as before we will run into the problem of: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\ln(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}) = \infty \cdot \ln(\frac ac) = \infty \cdot 0$$
an indeterminate form!

To fix that, we can rewrite the last limit to get $\frac 00$, let me show you:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\ln(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})}{\frac 1x} = \frac 00$$

$\frac 00$ is useful because we can use L'Hôpital's rule, so let's plug in the derivatives:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})}{\frac 1x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{ad-bc}{\left(ax+b\right)\left(cx+d\right)}}{- \frac {1}{x^2}}$$
Now we finally need to do some modifications to finish the limit as follows:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{ad-bc}{\left(ax+b\right)\left(cx+d\right)}}{- \frac {1}{x^2}} &= 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ad-bc}{(ax+b)(cx+d)} \cdot (-x^2)\\ 
&=
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ad-bc}{x(a+\frac bx)x(c+ \frac dx)} \cdot (-x^2) \\
&=
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ad-bc}{(a+\frac bx)(c+ \frac dx)} \cdot (-1) \\
&=
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{bc-ad}{(a+\frac bx)(c+ \frac dx)} \\
&=
\frac{bc-ad}{ac} \\
&=
\frac ba - \frac dc
\end{align}

Finally, we shouldn't forget that we applied $\ln$ at the start so we must **undo** it! To do that, we must apply $e$ to the result since $e^{\ln x} = x$.

So, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^x = e^{\frac ba - \frac dc}$$

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is break into cases:-

If $a>c$ . Then $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\to\frac{a}{c}>1$ as $x\to\infty$. Hence there exists some $M>0$ such that $x\geq M\implies \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}>r>1$ .

Hence $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^{x}>\lim_{x\to\infty}r^{x}\,,r>1$$. But the right hand side of this inequality tends to inftty and hence $\displaystyle(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^{x}\to\infty$ .

Similarly if $a<c$ you have the correspondingly $x\geq M\implies \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}<r<1$ .

This again gives you that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^{x}<\lim_{x\to\infty}r^{x}\,,r<1$$

And hence $\displaystyle(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^{x}\to 0$ .

If $a=c$.

Then we have the $1^{\infty}$ form. When $f(x)^{g(x)}$ have $1^{\infty}$ form we have:-

Then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\to\infty }(f(x)-1)g(x)\bigg)$.

This gives you $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})^{x}=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(b-d)x}{cx+d}\bigg)=\exp(\frac{b-d}{c})$$

Comment: I believe that's a duplicate answer to mine.

Comment: Do you see me using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @OmarDennaoui Your answer is still great btw (+1).

Comment: You're right, I apologize. I would like to note that I don't believe someone at the level of OP would know the formula $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\to\infty }(f(x)-1)g(x)\bigg)$ or is even expected to use it. (I might be wrong though!)

Comment: The op if I am not wrong is from a Computer Science background. So it might help the op to know this formula instead of going by L'Hopital which is more cumbersome for the $1^{\infty}$ case.

Comment: Indeed, more options the better!

Comment: That formula does not make sense. Set $f(x)=g(x)\equiv2$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=2^2=4$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-1)g(x)=1\cdot2=2$ and $4\neq e^2$

Comment: After some research, I see the conditions now. It would be good to add them, as they are important!

Comment: @FShrike It's for the $1^{\infty}$ form. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987215/1-to-the-power-of-infinity-formula